# Set Nativescript Chart Lines to Max Width

Tags: css, charts, nativescript

You can see from the image below, the chart lines don't go all the way to the edge of the StackLayout container.  I've tried adding negative margins on the StackLayout but they're inconsistent depending on how much data I have in the chart and the margins can fluctuate.  And between Android & iOS, the margins are always different.

Nativescript Playground sample:
play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=I8lOBP

This is the bad version:
[image]

In the image, you'll notice on the right and left edges, there's dark strips of the emulator window.  I'm looking for a way for the red area line to touch those edges. It's hard to see in the image but the bottom also needs to touch the bottom of the StackLayout container.

```
<StackLayout>
    <RadCartesianChart 
                height="100%"
                width="100%"
                class="default-background">
            <CategoricalAxis
                lineColor="#f5f5f5" 
                hidden="true" 
                lineHidden="true" 
                lineThickness="1"
                labelLayoutMode="Inner"
                tkCartesianHorizontalAxis>
            </CategoricalAxis>
            <LinearAxis
                lineColor="#f5f5f5"
                hidden="true" 
                lineHidden="true" 
                lineThickness="1"
                labelLayoutMode="Inner" 
                [maximum]="max"
                [minimum]="min"
                tkCartesianVerticalAxis>
            </LinearAxis>
            <AreaSeries
                tkCartesianSeries 
                seriesName="Area" 
                showLabels="false" 
                categoryProperty="Date" 
                [items]="areaSource$ | async"
                valueProperty="Amount" 
                selectionMode="None">
            </AreaSeries>
            <RadCartesianChartGrid 
                tkCartesianGrid 
                horizontalLinesVisible="false" 
                verticalLinesVisible="false" 
                verticalStripLinesVisible="false"
                horizontalStripLinesVisible="false" 
                horizontalStrokeColor="#181818">
            </RadCartesianChartGrid>
            <Palette tkCartesianPalette seriesName="Area">
                <PaletteEntry
                    tkCartesianPaletteEntry
                    opacity="1" 
                    [fillColor]="fillColor"
                    [strokeColor]="lineColor"
                    android:strokeWidth="4"
                    ios:strokeWidth="2">
                </PaletteEntry>
                <PaletteEntry 
                    tkCartesianPaletteEntry 
                    [fillColor]="fillColor" 
                    strokeColor="#181818" 
                    strokeWidth="0">
                </PaletteEntry>
            </Palette>
        </RadCartesianChart>
</StackLayout>
```

Here's what I want it to look like (credit: photoshop).
[image]

Comment: Can you setup a Playground?

Comment: Can you post the data `source` of the chart from the `ts` file?

Comment: It's dynamic data in the form ```[{Date: "01/19", Amount: 100}, {Date: "02/19",Amount: 200},...]```

Comment: is it possible to make JSFiddle or to put it somewhere so we can see live example?
It would help us solve it faster

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=I8lOBP
You can see that the chart, on BOTH android and ios don't stretch all the way to the edge of the screen.

Comment: @Manoj were you able to check out the playground?

Comment: As I could see in the Playground the space doesn't seem to be empty, that is the space on the left and right actually allocated to render the axis labels. Even if you turn the visibility off, the space is still consumed. Since the plugin is not open sourced one, it's difficult to debug. You may raise an issue at [Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues).

Comment: So you're saying, that extra space comes from the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the horizontalZoom property, probably upping its current value by about 30%.

Comment: I'll try that out.  I'm not sure it'll be consistent though.  Anytime I eyeball the percentage, margins, or etc it never renders correctly across devices.  Some devices may look right whereas others end up with gaps.  It needs to work like ```width="100%"``` where we know it'll go to the edge of the layout on every device.

Answer (score 0):

```
const screen = require("tns-core-modules/platform").screen;

        let widthDIPs = screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs;

    <StackLayout>
    <RadCartesianChart 
                height="100%"
                [width]="widthDIPs"
                class="default-background">
            <CategoricalAxis
               (...)
```

src: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/styling#supported-measurement-units